# Google Sheets API: What's the difference between the documentation's service vs google variables?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

There is some inconsistency in Google's Sheets API (node.js).

[Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values), they use

`service.spreadsheets.values.update({...`

and the service variable is nowhere to be defined

But [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs), they use

```
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
sheets.spreadsheets.values
```

What's the difference between `service` and `google` other than `service` never being defined?

Comment: ``service`` and ``sheets`` are can be used as the same. I think in the case of ``service.spreadsheets.values.update({...``, it supposes that ``service`` has already been declared elsewhere. It's ``const service = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});``.

Comment: That's probably the case, but is that mentioned anywhere in the docs?

Comment: In my environment, from Quickstart, I have used like this. I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Your link doesn't show the full code. Kindly recheck or post it here. Anyways, try looking up as 'service' might just be another variable.